# Service discovery stops working after a time

Tags: android, wifi-direct, service-discovery

I'm working on an app that uses service discovery. I followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html

I need to add local services and search for services from other devices at a certain interval of time. I noticed that the service discovery stops working after some time. 
If I add only about 4 ou 5 services in each device, the service discovery doesn't stop. When I add many services, the discovery stops working after some time.

I tried to clear local services but it didn't work. The strange is that I got no error messages while adding services or while searching for them. Simply I can't find anymore services.
Is there a limit of services one device can add?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve the problem?